# ssh key regeneration for github

Tags: macos, ssh, git

I was playing about with ssh keys, and stupidly deleted the github keys in my `.ssh` folder.

Now i get

`Error: Permission denied (public key)`

When i try and connect to a remote repo.

I have looked through the help page provided by [github] (https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) however i have not been able to figure it out.

`$ ssh -vT git@github.com` yields:

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

`ssh-add -l` yields:

The agent has no identities.

in `~/.ssh/` i no longer have `github_rsa` or `github_rsa.pub`, and `cat known_hosts` yields:

`github.com,204.232.175.90 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==`

I *think* the problem is with the keys, and that re-generating them may fix the problem -- but i am not sure. Is it possible to regenerate these keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create new keys for github.

In your accounts page, select 'SSH Keys'.  I'd delete the old public key and add the new public key.  Then use your private key to try connecting.